# Google Kubernetes Engine + Github Actions with google build workflow stuck at build step

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, github-actions, google-cloud-build

I've been trying to run Google Kubernetes Engine deploy action for my github repo.

I have made a github workflow job run and it is stuck at the build step, not updating. No matter how long I wait it is not changing its current state:

[image]

My dockerfile (I got it from the internet):

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Install.
RUN \
  sed -i 's/# \(.*multiverse$\)/\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y upgrade && \
  apt-get install -y build-essential && \
  apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
  apt-get install -y byobu curl git htop man unzip vim wget && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add files.
ADD root/.bashrc /root/.bashrc
ADD root/.gitconfig /root/.gitconfig
ADD root/.scripts /root/.scripts

# Set environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /root

# Define default command.
CMD ["bash"]
```

google.yml (The tamplate that github gave me):

```yaml
name: Build and Deploy to GKE

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "main"

env:
  PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.GKE_PROJECT }}
  GAR_LOCATION: europe-west1 # TODO: update region of the Artifact Registry
  GKE_CLUSTER: cluster-1    # TODO: update to cluster name
  GKE_ZONE: europe-west1   # TODO: update to cluster zone
  DEPLOYMENT_NAME: gke-deployment # TODO: update to deployment name
  REPOSITORY: samples # TODO: update to Artifact Registry docker repository
  IMAGE: static-site

jobs:
  setup-build-publish-deploy:
    name: Setup, Build, Publish, and Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production

    permissions:
      contents: 'read'
      id-token: 'write'

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    # Configure Workload Identity Federation and generate an access token.
    - id: 'auth'
      name: 'Authenticate to Google Cloud'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v0'
      with:
        token_format: 'access_token'
        workload_identity_provider: '---'
        service_account: '---'

    - name: Docker configuration
      run: |-
        echo ${{steps.auth.outputs.access_token}} | docker login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin https://$GAR_LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev
    # Get the GKE credentials so we can deploy to the cluster
    - name: Set up GKE credentials
      uses: google-github-actions/get-gke-credentials@v0
      with:
        cluster_name: ${{ env.GKE_CLUSTER }}
        location: ${{ env.GKE_ZONE }}

    # Build the Docker image
    - name: Build
      run: |-
        docker build \
          --tag "$GAR_LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/$REPOSITORY/$IMAGE:$GITHUB_SHA" \
          --build-arg GITHUB_SHA="$GITHUB_SHA" \
          --build-arg GITHUB_REF="$GITHUB_REF" \
          .
    # Push the Docker image to Google Artifact Registry
    - name: Publish
      run: |-
        docker push "$GAR_LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/$REPOSITORY/$IMAGE:$GITHUB_SHA"
    # Set up kustomize
    - name: Set up Kustomize
      run: |-
        curl -sfLo kustomize https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/releases/download/v3.1.0/kustomize_3.1.0_linux_amd64
        chmod u+x ./kustomize
    # Deploy the Docker image to the GKE cluster
    - name: Deploy
      run: |-
        # replacing the image name in the k8s template
        ./kustomize edit set image LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT_ID/REPOSITORY/IMAGE:TAG=$GAR_LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/$REPOSITORY/$IMAGE:$GITHUB_SHA
        ./kustomize build . | kubectl apply -f -
        kubectl rollout status deployment/$DEPLOYMENT_NAME
        kubectl get services -o wide
```

I'm trying to deploy a C++ code.

Comment: Are you using a GitHub runner or a self-hosted runner in your workflow? (Could you share the YAML file configurations in the question?)

Comment: @GuiFalourd Which part of the google.yml?

Comment: @GuiFalourd I have added the yml file.

Comment: Ok. A few more questions: Is it a public or private repository? Is it mandatory to use the `jobs.<jobid>.environment` configuration in the workflow?

Comment: @GuiFalourd It is a private repository. About the configuration part, I'm not sure I'm using the template that github actions gave me.

Comment: I understand your issue may be related to the environment field ([reference](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#about-environments)). As you'll see there, you can only configure environments for public repositories, and as all environment protection rules must pass before a job referencing the environment is sent to a runner, this may be the reason why your runner isn't starting.

Comment: @GuiFalourd I have fixed the error by changing my dockerfile, I've swapped it  with an example I found on the internet. However now it is stuck at the build step. I've updated the question.

Comment: Feel free to update the question or create another one in that case. Did you update the workflow file, or just the dockerfile? Let's wait until the end of the build step (see if it's a time out or if there is another error message).

Comment: @GuiFalourd just the dockerfile. It's been 30mins now and still no answers from github actions.

Comment: @GuiFalourd I havent updated my   REPOSITORY: samples IMAGE: static-site in relation to anything or did anything related to them. Could it be that? Also I don't have deployment.yml, kustomization.yml, service.yml, etc. Could it be that? If so what exactly am I supposed to write inside them.

Comment: It's probably that, as those values are used in that specific **Build** step. Without updating those variables according to your context, the docker command won't work as it would look for something that isn't configured.

Comment: @GuiFalourd Thank you, that helped. I've created an Artifact and linked it via REPOSITORY variable. In case someone needs it: after fixing this I have encountered an error where it asked me to specify a region/location but you can't chose inside github. you need to add : ``RUN apt-get update &&  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y tzdata`` to your dockerfile.

Comment: @GuiFalourd One more question: now it says it can't find kustomization.yaml but I have one inside my repo repo/.github/workloads/kustomization.yaml . Am I putting the file in the wrong location?

Comment: It's probably because it looks for the `kustomization.yaml` file in another folder (probably at the repository root). You could try using the [working-dir](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun) field to inform when the kubernetes command needs to be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue:

The problem is that when you say `FROM ubuntu:20.04` in your docker file it tries to use a full version of ubuntu and when it's done, just like you are installing ubuntu in your computer, it asks for the basic setup questions like "what is your timezone" or "create a user". You must either get a different version of ubuntu that is more fit for an image or simply add this line after your "FROM ubuntu:20.04" line:

```
RUN apt-get update &&  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y tzdata
```